# Apps script to delete all form questions except scpecific one

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, exception, reset

I have this function that resets my form. But I would like to delete all questions except the first one, so that the item ID and entry of this question remain fixed within a dynamic pre-filled link.
Note : the number of questions following the fist one varies, which is why I cannot point at the item IDs directly.

```
function resetform() {
var form=FormApp.openById(FORM_ID)
var items=form.getItems()
items.forEach(item=>form.deleteItem(item))
//1994309330 ==> the Item ID that I would like to keep in the delete process
}
```

Is there a way I can delete all items except item ID 1994309330 ?

I tried to replace
items.forEach(item=>form.deleteItem(item))

by
items.forEach(item !=1994309330 form.deleteItem(item))

but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to delete all items except for the item of item ID `1994309330`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please set your form ID to `FORM_ID`.

```js
function resetform() {
  var form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID);
  var items = form.getItems();
  items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.getId() != 1994309330) {
      form.deleteItem(item);
    }
  });
  //1994309330 ==> the Item ID that I would like to keep in the delete process
}
```

- When this script is run, all items except for the item of item ID `1994309330` are deleted.

#### Reference:

- [getId() of Interface Item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#getId())